# eclipse many little boxes under the main window

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-neon

I am using eclipse neon for Java development.  At the bottom of the eclipse window there should be one little box with 5 yellow icons/buttons in it: "Restore welcome", "Overview", "Tutorials", "Samples", and "What's new".

The problem is, I have 40 of them.  They appear one after the other, now in 4 rows at the bottom of the IDE. See below.

[image]

How can I trim them down to one?

Comment: share screenshot on http://imgur.com or attach here.

Comment: Here is the screenshot:    http://imgur.com/Imj9CdN

Comment: Seems a bug in neon and think it was got resolved. Just download latest available neon version. If not working then update your neon version details and OS using.

Comment: I updated to the newest neon, and indeed, the problem is resolved.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems a bug in older neon version on Linux and it already got resolved. Please download the latest available neon version and check.